# Disable Alt+Tab Tkinter - Standard Library

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to create a lock screen GUI so that I can effectively lock my PC without permissions to. In order to achieve this I need to be able to prevent the user from exiting the program.

Is there a way in which I can prevent the use of these while utilising the standard library in Python.

Comment: I sincerely hope that there is no such thing... then again, most full-screen games don't allow to alt-tab back to the desktop, so maybe look there?

Comment: On Windows you can lock the computer by typing the combination WindowsKey+L. The same thing can be done by sending a certain message to the Windows Program Manager, which could be done from Python by using the `ctypes` module. I'm not sure what you mean by "without permissions to".

Comment: We don't have permissions to lock the computer from the Ctrl+Alt+Delete screen at school for whatever reason so I am attempting to create my own solution to this.